# My objects are semi-transparent, and not one behind the other in the compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have multiple scenes each with different objects. I want to combine all these scenes in the compositor but when they render, all the objects from each scene overlap each other and are all transparent, so I can see all the objects when some should be hidden behind others.

To join my scenes I'm using a mix node with add.

Comment: Don't use add but alpha over. It would be easier to help you if you edit your question and add images of your current scene and nodes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/compositor-problems-when-working-with-alpha-over-and-blur-nodes/43581#43581

Answer (score 5):

What you describe as "transparent" is the result of **adding** the RGB pixel information of an image to that of the others.

When using **add** the pixel values of each of the images are summed and will make final image brighter.

[image]

If you want them to create the illusion of having one image in front of another, you need to use an alpha channel and have that control how images are combined.

A proposed workflow:

- Render each layer with a transparent background, to do that enable the Film Transparent Option for the scene.

[image]

- Use the alpha channel to determine how they combine over each other. The **[Alpha Over](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/alpha_over.html)** node is one of the options that will allow you to do that.

The node sockets to which the images are connected determines the result:

The **background** image should be connected to the **top socket**

The **foreground** image or scene to the **bottom socket**.

The foreground's alpha channel is used to control the overlay the foreground's RGB color information on to the background.

[image]

*click on the image to enlarge*

The most basic example would be like this: where the UFO is the foreground element and is combined over the landscape using the UFO image's Alpha Channel:

[image]

*click on the image to enlarge*

If you have more than two layers, you combine one on top of another, and then combine the result with yet another layer and so on like this:

[image]

*click on the image to enlarge*

Note that if the background image has an alpha channel, both alphas are combined.

[image]
*click on the image to enlarge*

**An alternative to the Alpha Over node** would be using a [RGB mix node](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/color/mix.html?highlight=mix%20node#mix-node) and using the Alpha channel of the foreground layer control the mix with the background:

[image]

*click on the image to enlarge*

Another example:

A simple scene: Three circles, the red is on top of the others and the green on top of the blue one. They've been separated in different layers.

[image]

Using the add operation will result on the **sum** of the values for each pixel for each of the RGB channels of the image, a simple A+B operation.

See what happens where the circles overlap, where each of the RGB values of a layer are added on to those of the other layers:

[image]

The Alpha over operation is a bit more complex: A+B(1-alpha)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do this you should not use an add node.

Instead use an alpha over if you want to combine different render layers.
[image]

Comment: Hi Delagone :) Please notify the commenter first or add more to it, see: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-to-do-with-questions-which-have-been-answered-in-comments/437#437

Comment: Hi, you're right. I'm kinda new to the community and still figuring some stuff out. will do that in the future.