# Object appears transparent in render but not in viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I've made a simple motion tracking scene with a cube breaking on a surface.

When I see the viewport render using Shift-Z, everything appears as expected.

When I render the final image, the cubes appear seethrough

[image: Preview Render]
[image: Final Render]
[[image: Nodes][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxPfI.png)

Comment: Did you check your compositor setup (poststamp/picture icon in the Node editor). Did you check the visibility of your objects in Viewport vs Render (eye vs camera icon)

Comment: [Here's the compositor node view](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cxPfI.png) - not sure what I'm looking at though

Comment: please include it into the question, it is important

Comment: Not enough rep - I can only include 2 links

Comment: You might want to look into a tutorial for this. To get a somewhat realistic result you should include a plane for the cubes to cast a shadow onto (the virtual desk plane)

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the tracking feature, blender sets the compositor up using three layers:

One Layer is the movie, on layer is the objects you want to add, and one layer is the shadow/ao layer to project the shadow and ambient occlusion from the object to the background(movie).

As I can see from your nodesetup, the cubes are only visible on the background layer, but not on the foreground layer. Meaning you see the shadows and ambient occlusion but not the object iteself. Thus you have to

- either adjust the visible layers in the render layer setup
- or move the cubes to a layer that is rendered to foreground (probably the first layer, the second layer usually includes a plane to cast the shadow on)