# Only a shadow of the 3d object over the background is visible in the render

Tags: rendering

[image]

I'm new to blender. Actually very new. I searched for this in the discussions. But none of them solved the problem I have not done anything with nodes. I guess I'm going to watch some tutorials for that. But the problem is everything is completely fine in the rendered view option but as soon as I render image it renders like that below. I tried changing a lot of things, nothing changed.Plzz help me out!

Here is the blend file: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are multiplying the image on top of the background.

Use alpha over to place the render layer over the background.
[image]

> Use this node to layer images on top of one another. This node takes two images as input, combines them with a factor, and outputs the image. Connect the Background image to the top input, and the foreground image to the lower input. Where the foreground image pixels have an alpha greater than 0 (namely, have some visibility), the background image will be overlaid.

Please read the manual: https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/color/alpha_over.html?highlight=alpha%20over

Comment: Somehow related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137