# Joining render layers

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers

Obviously the opacity isn't what I want lol. I'm a little stuck on how to merge

Little bit closer, but it's still transparent... 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't use the image as fac for the mix. Most likely you need to use Alpha over instead of a color mix node, but to give you a complete answer we need complete information. Please add an image that shows your complete node tree.

Comment: probably related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137

Comment: @cegaton Sorry, there you go. (I'll make the changes you recommended).

Comment: @cegaton Alpha over worked perfectly. Thank you