# Why is my model see through when I render?

Tags: tracking

When I render my 3D motion Tracked Scene It is See Through and I can see an outline. Please tell me why this is happening. It would be greatly apprieciated.[image]

Comment: Could you post your compositing node setup?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137