# How do I make my layers appear in a certain orientation?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes, render-layers

Okay, so I am working on this little pet project just for fun. It's a wallpaper for my friend with his gamertag. My problem, is that I can't seem to find the right node orientation/ settings to get his tag to appear in FRONT of the shockwave. Everything I try won't help, and it still looks like it's either between the red and purple, or behind both. Anyone got any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This is not easy to answer if we don't know how you combined your elements on the first place. Use the [edit] link and add an image of your compositng nodes and explain roughly what the render layers contain.

Comment: meybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137

Comment: That link actually gave me exactly what I wanted. Thanks for that!