# How do I mix more than one image with a video in node editor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, tracking

I'm trying to add images to a video clip using motion tracking, and while I can do this fine for one image in a clip, I can't figure out how to have more than one image added to the video. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show screenshots of what you've got so far in the compositor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mix more than one image you concatenate nodes: the result of one mix node gets connected to the next node as input.

For example:

[image]

It is important to know what kind of operation you want to use to mix the images. (read the [manual page for the mix node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/mix.html) for more info)

If you are mixing images with alpha channel, use the [**Alpha Over**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/alpha_over.html) node instead. Read this related link: [My objects are semi-transparent, and not one behind the other in the compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137)