# Help to combine three render layers

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm using composition but I can't combine my render layers: can anyone help me?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdGv-rcTJn0
[image]

Comment: Hi, the node details are so small that it's really hard to see them... you could help others showing better those nodes and/or describing with text which layers you are trying to combine and how. I (guess) see two "image" layers combined with "add" node with factor "1", then an "alpha over" node which combines another "image" layer... can you explain somehow what are you trying to achieve with those three layers?

Comment: using mix and alpha over

Comment: ok, better but, we know nothing about the three images that those layers are trying to combine, and you also say nothing about how thay should combine... should they just overlay? has the top one some level of transparency (since you're using alpha over)? describe in words what you're trying to achieve if possible... for the "mix" node, see which blend mode to use, here (examples) https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/mix.html

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBRMh5QZ1n8&t=1440s

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137

Comment: is no use,nothing can fix it

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84712/how-do-i-mix-more-than-one-image-with-a-video-in-node-editor/84716#84716

Comment: no still dont do nothing

Answer (score 2):

You are not using transparency in any of your render layers.

Without an alpha channel the Alpha Over operation will not work!

Turn on Shading > Alpha: Transparent.

[image]