# Concatenate Movies Compositor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, movie-clip-editor

I have two movies considered as images (because I need to set up the beginning frame, offset ...) and I want to concatenate them so that one appears before the other one.

Is there an operation in the compositor which can do this ?

[image: Compositor]

As mentionned here :

docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/mix.html

the mix node needs a background image and a foreground one. I don't want to mix but to put one movie one after the other after specific frame.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84712/how-do-i-mix-more-than-one-image-with-a-video-in-node-editor/84716#84716

Comment: A mix node seems to render simultaneously the two movies. How can I tell to put one after the other ? Should I adjust the values of "Offset" and "Start Frame" ?

Comment: Check out my blog entry on the use of Frame, Start Frame and Length  https://broadcastblender.wordpress.com/2017/02/09/imagemovie-node-basics-b3d/

Answer (score 1):

***Frames*** will give you control on the source’s duration (in frames): How many frames do you want to use? Playback will repeat the last frame unless you choose Cyclic* (see below)

[image: image node values]

***Start Frame*** is the frame in the scene at which the video clip will start playing.

***Offset*** allows you to select the first frame of the video source.

Cyclic* will make the cycle of frames start over. If you want to hold a frame, before or after the specified number of frames or freeze a frame you would need to disable this box.