# Alpha compositing with layer masking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, transparency, render-layers

Ahhh yes this problem again...

So I have a rather complex set of compositing layers to set up, some nodes masking areas and others just splitting up the scene components. Now I've run into this issue many times while compositing with trees or vegetation, but the only method that I've found to work doesn't allow for a lot of flexibility.

To composite layers I find I need to use layer masking to allow for objects to appear in front of each other, but when using mask layers on objects with tons of transparency, the camera doesn't register the z depth correctly and just renders the entire mesh. This blocks other objects when combining layers.

[image]

Is there a better way to combine layers with lots of transparency? I cannot put the trees on the same layer as other objects because they all use different compositing effects.

Compositor if needed:
[image]

Cheers,

Comment: I can't understand your node tree, but it looks like you are using a color mix node in Add mode almost exclusively to combine the different elements. Use alpha channels, masks to control the layering along with Alpha Over nodes (instead of add). See:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137

Comment: While that was very close to what I was looking for, your post certainly put me on the right track. I never new that the environment pass was an option for each layer. Now while this does make things more complicated the scene finally works. Thank you!

Comment: Hows this for an increase in complicatedness: https://puu.sh/zxugi/f61b368b2a.png

Comment: The image is so low resolution that it is unreadable... Use Ctrl+F3 to do screen grabs.