# How do I get a transparent background with multiple render layers

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, layers

I am trying to get an animation that has 3 render layers to have a transparent background.

How would I do this?

Simply checking the transparent box under film does not work with multiple layers

Thanks for any help.

(Cycles)[image]

Comment: Are you using **alpha over**? Read this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137

Comment: Yes I am. I will add a picture to show you the nodes.

Comment: If you don't show an image of the result is hard to guess what the problem is. I suspect that what you are doing is correct but you are not able to display it properly in the compositor viewer due to a limitation of blender. It cannot display associated alpha correctly, and cannot display in RGBA pixels that are emissive and transparent at the same time (blurs and glows in this case). Your file is OK. Use RGB to display it. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824