# Object is transparent against background

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting, volumetrics

This scene was nice to work with for a while, but somehow I managed to push a button that makes the objects transparent against the background. How can I get this back to normal?[image]

Comment: Is there some reason you're not connecting the image through the background node?

Comment: Connect the image texture to the background node and the background node to the World output, but that is not the issue. Please [edit] your question and add an image of the nodes for the material of the plane. And also show the nodes used in the compositor. It looks to me that you are adding render layers on the background instead of using alpha over.

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137

Comment: The background node is the one I used first. Then the image became very blue. Then I added the environment-node with the HDRI. Then the transparency became obvious. I was recommended to uncheck camera in the ray visibility section. That turned the world black but the contrast on the plane good.

Comment: Again, **[edit]** your question and add detailed information and images that might help others help you.

Comment: I gave up. Imported the plane to a new scene and the problem was gone. Most of the work was left to do and I had to get on with it. I thank you for your engagement.